# Window resize function not working with flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, video

I am using the code snippet from video for everybody to embed a video in my site. The snippet basically guarantees more or less that the user will be able to see the video from any device. Here is my html:

```
<div class="intermitent-video-container">
    <video controls="controls" poster="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" width="640" height="360">
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="100%" height="100%"> 
            <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['http%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.thewikies.com%2Fvfe-generator%2Fimages%2Fbig-buck-bunny_poster.jpg',{'url':'http%3A%2F%2Fclips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de%2Fbig_buck_bunny.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />
            <img alt="Big Buck Bunny" src="http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg" width="640" height="360" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
        </object>
    </video>
</div>
```

To control the sizing & aspect ratio of this video for responsive layout I have the following Javascript:

```
function resizeVideo() {
  var videoWidth = jQuery(".intermitent-video-container").width();
  var videoHeight = videoWidth * 0.666;
  jQuery(".intermitent-video-container").css('height',videoHeight);
};

resizeVideo();
jQuery(window).resize(resizeVideo);
```

The snippet above works exactly as I want except for when the video fallback goes to the flash version of the video. When I load the page in `Safari 5.1.7` which uses flash for example the video will size exactly how I want it using the code snippet above on load but not on window resize. Is this a limitation to flash or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Adding css for video tag

```
video{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

And you absolutely sure **intermitent-video-container** have responsive.
Note: Dont forget `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`in your head HTML

Comment: does not fix the problem unfortunately